# mysql load data infile with replace

Tags: mysql

I have tab-separated results.csv file (sorry, tabs are not supported here):

```
id  level
1   
2
```

I load it in mysql 5.6 and everything is ok (warnings are not critical for me):

```
mysql> create table test(id int auto_increment primary key, level int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.11 sec)
```

```
mysql> load data local infile 'results.csv' into table test ignore 1 lines (id, level);
Query OK, 2 rows affected, 2 warnings (0.01 sec)
Records: 2  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 2

Warning (Code 1366): Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'level' at row 1
Warning (Code 1261): Row 2 doesn't contain data for all columns
```

But when I try to load it with **replace** I got error (why not warning???):

```
mysql> load data local infile 'results.csv' replace into table test ignore 1 lines (id, level);
ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'level' at row 1
```

Why does it work this way?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a var for null values

```
load data local infile 'results.csv' into table 
test ignore 1 lines 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "\t"
(id, @level) 
set level = NULLIF(@level, '')
```